# ZipFile constructor slow for zip64 file in Java/Apache Commons Compress

Tags: java, zip

I have to read file from zip file that contains over 100000 files and I am using Java 1.6 so I use Apache commons compress library for the time being.  However, the constructor of ZipFile() takes around 30 seconds to return. (I admit the machine I am on is pretty out of date, an C2D E6550 with 8GB RAM, but if the zip file has less than 65535 files, the constructor returns almost immediately)

Now I need to speeding it up because our program opens zip files very frequently and the time it takes for ZipFile constructor is simply too long.  I have two options:
1) split the zip file into volumes each with <65535 files 
or
2) cache ZipFile object and reuse it

However, both takes significant amount of refactoring/rewrite so before I go on with either solution, is there a way to speed up reading the zipfile with a different library or I am doing something wrong with Apache commons compress?  This is how I create the zipfile object:

```
final File f =  new File(zipFileName);
if(f.exists() == false)
    throw new FileNotFoundException(zipFileName);
ZipFile zip = new ZipFile(f);
```

Any thoughts on how to attack this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From looking at the [source code](http://commons.apache.org/compress/apidocs/src-html/org/apache/commons/compress/archivers/zip/ZipFile.html), it is opening the zipfile and reading all the entries immediately.  It stores this information in internal hashmaps which are not originally sized appropriately for your use case.  All the rehashing could be the issue.  But it is hard to be sure.  You should execute it with a profiler to see where the time is being spent.

You could also grab the source for apache commons and make your own version which allows you to control the initial sizing to see if that helps.

If not, you could always construct this object in a separate thread and do something else useful while it is being constructed.

Comment: followed your suggestion and changed the initial size of the hashmap, and ran profiler to check the time it took for the constructor to finish.  It cut the time in half, but still way over our budget. I guess I will have to bite the bullet and do some refactoring in my code.

Comment: If you are able to change the hashmap to a treemap. You could also always shell-out to the zip unix command, but htat might "break the rules."

Comment: @sam thanks for suggesting the tree map.  However, by specifying a pre-defined size (say 100000) for the map, the time for the map creation no longer is the bottleneck.  It's the other function that scan through the central directory of the zip file that's taking up all the time.  But given the fact that it has to scan through 100000 records, it's hard to expect it to finish quickly.

Comment: What is the result of your research? Do you overcome your problem?

Comment: @EugeneGoza we end up changing our source processing to split the zip files so they stay within zip32 instead of going up to zip64.  Turns out that's easier than optimizing zip64 parsing.